# windowleaked in android view

Tags: java, android, screen-orientation

Hi I have developed android phonegap app and when dialog is shown and screen orientation changes,showing the error in logcat.How to solve this

Here is my logcat error:

```
E/WindowManager(5759): Activity com.example.Service.NotificationAlert has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@412c93c0 that was originally added here
E/WindowManager(5759): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.Service.NotificationAlert has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@412c93c0 that was originally added here
E/WindowManager(5759):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:344)
E/WindowManager(5759):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:267)
E/WindowManager(5759):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:215)
E/WindowManager(5759):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:140)
E/WindowManager(5759):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
E/WindowManager(5759):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:278)
E/WindowManager(5759):  at com.example.Service.NotificationAlert$1.handleMessage(NotificationAlert.java:103)
E/WindowManager(5759):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/WindowManager(5759):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/WindowManager(5759):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/WindowManager(5759):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/WindowManager(5759):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/WindowManager(5759):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
E/WindowManager(5759):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
E/WindowManager(5759):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please tell me the solution.Thanks In Advance.

Here is my code:

```
 AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(NotificationAlert.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Mobilyzer");
    msgCountBundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    messageCount = msgCountBundle.getInt("Count");
    userId = msgCountBundle.getInt("userid");
    if (messageCount > 1) {
        alertDialog
                .setMessage("You have " + messageCount + " New Messages");
    } else {
        alertDialog.setMessage("You have " + messageCount + " New Message");
    }

alertDialog.show();
new Timer().schedule(new task(), 30000);

private class task extends TimerTask 
{
    public void run() 
    {
        toastHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}

private final Handler toastHandler = new Handler() {
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        if(alertDialog.isShowing())
        {
            try
            {
                alertDialog.dismiss();
                finish();
                Log.i("alertdialog","hide alert dialog");
            }
            catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                Log.e("illegal ","illegal exception in dialog"+e);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("illegal ","exception in dialog"+e);
            }
        }
        Log.i("alertdialog","show alert dialog");
    }
};
```

Comment: paste some code to get more exact answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `NotificationAlert` `Activity` you are showing a `Dialog` that was not dismissed by explicitly calling `dismiss()` on it when `Activity` was paused. Keep a reference to your `Dialog` object and in `onPause()` call `dismiss()` on it.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (myDialog != null) {
        myDialog.dismiss();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply.But i need to dismiss the dialog in timertask.How to fix this problem...

Comment: At the end of your `run()` of `TimerTask` add this code: `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {

   @Override
   public void run() {
    if (myDialog != null) {
     myDialog.dismiss();
    }
   }
  });`

Comment: But `TimerTask` must finish its `run()` before `Activity` pauses. **Or** add dismiss code in `onPause()` as well.

Comment: dismiss code in onPause() works fine.When i change the orientation whether onPause() will be called or not.I need to solve this problem in android 2.2 and greater than 4.0

Comment: I couldn't understand what you said but yes changing orientation will automatically call `onPause()`, if that's what you asked.

Comment: ya,thats what i need.Whether this may cause anyother problem,because i am calling NotificationAlert activity from timer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25149/discussion-between-m-wajeeh-and-javah)

Answer (score 0):

Check the flow of application .In application you are adding dialog more than one time i think.So, try to solve by adding only one dialog in to activity view.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of some other exception the app is crashing and because the dialog is showing the window leak exception is thrown.

Anyways the window leak exception occurs when the dialog is not null and the activity is finished. So the dialog has to be made null either in onPause() as mentioned above or where the activity is moving to a new screen like before starting an intent.  Here you can nullify the dailog in the catch so that the window leak exception can be handled, but there is some other exception in your code. Provide the complete logcat.